# ¿Cómo unir dos dataframe con pandas, utilizando más de una fila de evaluación?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo 5 `dataframes` distintos

Y ya pude unir dos de ellos, realizando solo una consulta de fila, ya que esos dos me lo permitían.

A ese nuevo `dataframe` el cual llamo `df6`, necesito adjuntar los otros 3 `dataframes`, validando el `datetime` y el `machineID`, pero al momento de hacer el merge con esas dos variables dice que no es soportado

```
df7=pd.merge(df6, df3, on='machineID'&'datetime')
```

Arrojándome este error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Si utilizo `how='inner'` o `how='outer'`
no tengo el resultado esperado, ya que agrega columnas, no genera las filas que necesito.

Comment: en `df6` tienes `machineID` y en `df3` tienes `datetime` ? y quieres hacer el  `merge`  en base a esas dos columnas ?

Comment: en ambos tengo machineID y datetime, lo que quiero es validar las dos y entonces poner la columna extra q es error

Comment: intenta `on=['machineID','datetime'] `.